# Should all by-design questions on meta have the by-design tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a lot of questions on meta where the answer is a nice explanation of the rationale behind a certain behavior, and as long as someone reads the entire answer it's obvious that it's by design. However, I guess that many are only interested in knowing whether or not if it's by design or if it's a bug, and don't necessarily want to read the entire explanation. The thing is: a lot of these question don't have the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag.

I tried flagging a question where I proposed to add the tag [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). It was approved and the tag was added, so this was apparently not a wrong flag. I'm tempted to flag such questions as I encounter them in order to get the correct tags on questions, but I'm wondering if this would just create a bunch of extra work for the mods, compared to the benefit of having correct tags.

So, my question is: Should I flag questions that have by-design answers in order to get correct tags, or should I just leave them be?

Comment: IMO, leave them be.  Moderators have enough to worry about without having to edit countless posts to add a tag.

Comment: @bluet that would involve giving nicael a diamond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go out of your way to flag them, the ones that remain relevant tend to surface naturally as folks find them to use as reference when answering new questions. When *that* happens, the tag usually gets applied.

The mod that services your flag may not be sure if something *should* have that tag, thus it may soak for a while, or just get marked helpful without action. The by-design answers are what matter the most, the tag is more or less a spoiler to that, and a means of getting bugs / features off of an active filtered view.

You're not doing anything wrong by flagging them, but it wouldn't be the most *ideal* use of time.

Comment: Or, well, just changing [bug] for [support] ;)